# Creating advanced http entity with Android

Tags: android, http

I need to create a httpentiy like this:

```
"project" => {"name" => "lorem", "description" => "ipsum"}
```

for my RoR webservice

my code:

```
    private String postData(String url, String user, String password, ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException
{
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    HttpClient httpclient = this.getDefaultHttpClient(20000, user, password);
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse r = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    return inputStreamToString(r.getEntity().getContent());
}
```

that allows my only to do somthing like this:

```
"name" => "lorem", "description" => "ipsum"
```

has anyone a clean solution?

Comment: show how you are setting values to nameValuePairs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this solves your problem...

`List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("project[name]", "Dinash"));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("project[description]", "dina"));`